# TinyMCE codesample plugin dialog height

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Does anyone know how to change the height of this popup? They use javascript to set the height which is far too much on a small laptop. It's somehow possible to overwrite the styles with important declarations in the css but that feels messy. I wish there was a property that could be used in the init method of TinyMCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There are now configuration options for controlling the width and height of the dialog:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/#codesample_dialog_width
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/#codesample_dialog_height

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** There is currently no configuration option to control this ... you can certainly change this in the plugin's code.  In the 4.3.12 version of TinyMCE I changed the code on lines 1103 and 1104 to this:

```
open: function(editor) {
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: "Insert/Edit code sample",
            minWidth: Math.min(DOM.getViewPort().w, 600),
            minHeight: Math.min(DOM.getViewPort().h, 450),
```

This reduced the width and height of the editor.  Of course if you update TinyMCE you would need to re-add this change but its a pretty simple update.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Hope they make it a config option.